# Почему в java рекомендуется называть класс с большой буквы?

Tags: style, java, code-style, классы

Почему в java рекомендуется называть класс с большой буквы?

Comment: отвечу вопросом на вопрос: "а почему девушек называют именами Елена, Таня, Оксана а именами Коля, Петр, Дмитрий - нет ?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала, давайте ответим на вопрос: а почему вообще нужны какие-то рекомендации по называнию классов? Вот бы каждый писал как ему вздумается, было бы наверное неплохо?

На самом деле, не так уж и хорошо. Дело в том, что в серьёзных проектах большая часть времени расходуется не на написание кода, а на его поддержку. Причём код поддерживает обычно не тот, кто его написал. Если код написан в одинаковом стиле, его легче понимать: не приходится подстраиваться под индивидуальный стиль каждого нового автора. Поэтому руководители крупных проектов часто (если не всегда) *требуют* от программистов соблюдения общепринятого стиля.

Почему этим правилам должны следовать вы, если вы не пишете большой коммерческий проект? Потому что вам же будет лучше: вы привыкнете писать код в определённом стиле, и когда пойдёте на работу, ваш стиль будет выглядеть профессионально, что вызывает положительное отношение к вам. И вам не придётся привыкать к стилю других, что тоже немаловажно: в первые недели работы в новой компании и так много трудностей.

Отлично, почему же именно с большой буквы? Дело в том, что надо было установить *хоть какое-то* правило. Сообщество Java приняло такой стандарт (а может, Гослингу так понравилось), более-менее произвольно, важно было лишь чтобы стандарт существовал. И теперь нам ничего не остаётся, как следовать этому стандарту.

Кстати, в Java есть ещё много других правил именования. Вот они все: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Для классов (вольный перевод):

> Имя класса должно быть существительным. Если оно состоит из нескольких слов, слова пишутся вместе, каждое с большой буквы. Старайтесь, чтобы ваши имена классов были простыми и выразительными. Избегайте сокращений и аббревиатур (за исключением популярных и устоявшихся, наподобие URL или HTML).

Answer (score 10):

Чтобы исключить подобные ситуации:

```
class myclass {
    static int myclass; 
}

myclass myclass = new myclass();
myclass.myclass = myclass.hashCode();
```

Немного путает, не правда ли?

Comment: А это будет работать? Простите за, возможно, глупый вопрос. Не силен в java.

Comment: Сам не силён, но по-моему да, регистр букв имеет значение.

Comment: Будет. Можете проверить.

Comment: так это же C#, только наоборот, у них там методы с большой =)

Comment: @Gorets В C# имена локальных переменных всё же в нижнем регистре )

Comment: При объявлении класса модификатор `static` забыли =)

Answer (score 7):

Просто чтобы не путаться. Это никак не влияет на работу программы. К тому же если все программы на java будут написаны в одном стиле - будет гораздо приятней их читать.

Answer (score 5):

Это рекомендация и не более того, но рекомендация хитрая - ниже я покажу почему.

Есть такое понятие как стиль кодирования. Давным давно, когда топикстартёр ходил под стол пешком, умные дяди из Sun Microsystems для облегчения своей жизни придумали стиль кодирования Java и опубликовали его в виде [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Конечно, можно нас*ать на эту рекомендацию и кодировать как сами решите, но как говорится, если вы хотите иметь гордое звание джавера то надо придерживаться корпоративной этики, а стиль кодирования, особенно [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) - это как бы некая лейбла, знак принадлежности к цеху Java программистов.

Если придете устраиваться на работу и на собеседовании начнете писать не придерживаясь общепринятых стандартов (особенно, еще раз не поленюсь подчеркнуть **naming convention**), то с большой долей вероятности вам откажут в трудоустройстве. А бабки - это уже серьезно.

Так что думайте.

**Update**

Комментарии закончились, посему выкладываю апдейт сюда:

Я ни на что не обиделся, а гордым именем **Джавер** я реально горжусь. И если кому-то это кажется созвучным **Жабер**, я не виноват.

По-поводу истории Java: начнем с того, что Java развивался сначала вне Sun (по крайней мере по словам Гослинга) - он сначала придумал подобие виртуальной машины для Pascal на DEC/VAX еще студентом. Затем был проект Oak и проч. (в рамках Sun) который начался в 90-м году (Остерхаут покинул Sun в 94-м), далее уже из Oak выросла Java. Как рассказывал Гослинг название Java было дано по аналогии с дешевым кофе (из Явы) - типа как язык для программирования бытовой техники, кофе-машин, холодильников и проч. Не зря логотип Java до сих пор это чашка кофе.

Вот такая история: поведанная отцом-основателем и старательно записанная мной.

Comment: Гордое имя Жабера -- это звучит! Речь уже об идеологии (а ято насчет слухов, что причиной рождения джавы явился уход Остерхута из "Сан") или фокусов с трудоустройством (не придерживаешься ритуала -- не наш человек)?

Comment: Я как-то был на лекции Джеймса Гослинга (для тех кто в танке - создателя Java) - он рассказывал историю языка немного по другому :)

Comment: @alexlz: давайте не опускаться до оскорблений. Мы здесь ведь не для этого, правда? Разработчик, пишущий на Java, может быть хорошим и плохим, точно так же как и разработчик на ассемблере. И да, даже разработчик на Коболе может гордится своим кодом, если этот код хорош.

Comment: @Barmaley звучит как угроза)) Завидую тихо)

Comment: @VladD Никого не хотел обидеть, тем более оскорбить. Если получилось -- приношу извинения.

@Barmaley насчёт истории java я не шибко грамотен, источник информации указал. Но то, что java была создана после ухода Osterhaut'а -- медицинский факт. Возможно, на tcl/tk Sun возлагал не такие надежды, как утверждал вышеупомянутый слух -- может быть, на то он и слух.

Comment: @alexlz: Мне показалось, в ответе @Barmaley "гордое имя" употреблялось скорее иронично, чем серьёзно.

Comment: @alexlz, все таки tcl/Tk и Java настолько разные языки (я бы даже сказал, что у них разные экологические ниши), что в связь между уходом Osterhaut'а и создением Java верится с трудом.

Comment: @VladD Нет, не показалось. И "скорее" тут явно излишне. А так... перечитайте, что Вы сами про языки написали. С этими словами я полностью согласен.

Comment: @alexlz, @VladD смотрите апдейт

Comment: @Barmaley Ну Гослинга я не слушал, да и из языков свободно владею только русским и русским матерным, но версия, что java -- это религия, имеет некоторые основания.

@avp насчёт ниш tcl/tk и java -- разговор долгий и здесь неуместный. Но хохмы ради могу отметить, что тиклеты для браузеров (msie и netscape) я в 90е годы видел. Прикольно.

И создание языка java -- это одно, а мощные инвестиции Sun -- немножко другое.

Comment: @alexlz, а создание Java и инвестиции Sun неотрывны одно от другого. Билл Джой, будучи одним из основателей Sun в начале 90-х по моему принимал очень активное участие в проектах Oak->Java.

Answer (score 0):

Всё намного проще, чем вы думаете! Писать имена классов с большой буквы и т.д. было решено не только сообществом java. По-моему даже есть концепция о составлении имён классов.

Comment: Конечно, соглашений о названиях много, и надо было лишь выбрать какое-нибудь. Вот список: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_%28programming%29