# Не переходит на другое активити

Tags: android, java

Вот код, в Манифесте все указал, на `lay_pleci_1` переходит, а вот на `lay_plechi_2` уже нет

```
public class lay_pleci extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnBack;
Button btnList2;
Button btnList3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_pleci);
    btnList2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList2);
    btnList3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList3);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnList2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnList3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        //делаем действие
        case R.id.btnBack:
            Intent MyActivity;
            MyActivity = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            startActivity(MyActivity);
            break;
        case R.id.btnList2:
            Intent List2;
            List2 = new Intent(this, lay_pleci_1.class);
            startActivity(List2);
            break;
        case R.id.btnList3:
            Intent List3;
            List3 = new Intent(this, lay_plechi_2.class);
            startActivity(List3);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
<activity android:name=".lay_sheya">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".lay_pleci"">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".lay_trapecia">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".lay_triceps">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".lay_pleci_1">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".lay_plechi_2">
</activity>
<activity
 android:name=".MyActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

**lay pleci 1**

```
public class lay_pleci_1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_pleci_1);

    Button btnBack;
    Button btnList1;
    Button btnList3;

    btnList1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList1);
    btnList3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList3);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnList1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnList3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        //делаем действие
        case R.id.btnBack:
            Intent MyActivity;
            MyActivity = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            startActivity(MyActivity);
            break;
        case R.id.btnList1:
            Intent List1 = new Intent(this, lay_pleci.class);
            this.startActivity(List1);
            break;
        case R.id.btnList3:
            Intent List3 = new Intent(this, lay_plechi_2.class);
            this.startActivity(List3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: lay_pleci_1.class  это имя класса? это грустно

Comment: покажи лучше манифест еще

Comment: может в разных пакетах лежат активити? пропиши путь полностью, есть логи ошибки? добавь логов в онКлик

Comment: @alex11, у меня для вас есть отличный совет: **не делайте приложения для Android.**  Потому как из-зи таких, как вы, становится еще больше таких, как вы..

Comment: амфитаминщик прав ))

Comment: @Heisenberg, а у меня для вас тоже наиотличнейший совет, не сидите на этом сайте, раз вы не довольны такими, как я. Я не учился в спец. вузах и не ходил на кружки инф-матики. Я - самоучка и пытаюсь разобраться в данной среде, это естественно, что у меня что-то не будет получаться, именно поэтому я и зарегистрировался на этом сайте, чтобы задавать вопросы. И не вам решать делать ли мне приложения или нет. А ваша фраза..."Из-за таких, как вы, становится еще больше таких, как вы..", я их не порождаю.

Comment: @Gorets, должен поправить вас: я **"метамфетаминщик"**

---

@alex11, вы даже не сумели уловить идею моей фразы выше. А процесс самообразования, как ни крути, начинается с книжек и электронных мануалов, а не с загаживания форумов..

Comment: @alex11, что происходит по нажатию на кнопку для перехода на ay_plechi_2?

Comment: @Heisenberg, оу, вы серьезно? Найдите хоть одну книжку где описывается моя проблема(И да, я читал спец.книги, без них никак), и я откажусь от разработки приложений!
___________________________________
@metalurgus, приложение останавливается.

Comment: @alex11, книжку? - пожалуйста - Android 4 от Рето Майера. Но для простоты, вот вам ссылка на одну из статей - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php .

Теперь откажитесь от разработки под Android?)

Comment: @0xFFh, вы хоть вниклись, в то, что я писал? "Найдите мне книжку, где описывается моя проблема", но вместо этого вы мне скинули урок и книжку, где нет моей проблемы, там разбирают открытие активити, в этих вопросах я разобрался, но при открытии одного из, высвечивается ошибка, хотя все сделано правильно. Но что вы, многоуважаемые программисты, вы, вместо помощи, даете только...хотя, вы ничего не даете, за исключением некоторых, которые действительно помогают, огромное им спасибо!

Comment: @alex11 покажите ошибку в логах.

Comment: @monomi, http://i68.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0811/dd/0309ad21f5e508d9d2ddd6620540e2dd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставлю здесь:

[Правила написания кода на Java](http://www.lar.ru/blog/2009/03/16/175)

[Почему в java рекомендуется называть класс с большой буквы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/168987/class-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-java-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B)

[Пишем красивый код](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/mememe.php)

[Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Answer (score 1):

lay_plechi_2 в 25 строчке ошибка, т.е. на активити переходит, но в нем ошибка

Comment: в onCreate что то с вьюхами намутил 100%