# Android code style

Tags: java, android, code-style

Здравствуйте!

Хочу узнать о правилах именования полей в "Android". Читал статью [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html). Остановился на именовании полей, решил отойти от привычных способов писать код в проекте по "гайдлайнам". Никак не могу привыкнуть. Код стал менее читабельным, раздражают приставки к именам переменных, отсутствие **this** в конструкторах.

Насколько оправдано использование данного соглашения?

Когда среда разработки сама помогает понять что мы видим?

Не будет ли считаться, что код написанный игнорируя данный стандарт, не качественный?

```
// Этот класс взят из вышеупомянутой статьи
public class MyClass {
    public static final int SOME_CONSTANT = 42;
    public int publicField;
    private static MyClass sSingleton;
    int mPackagePrivate;
    private int mPrivate;
    protected int mProtected;
}
```

Конструктор выглядит теперь так:

```
class MyClass(Context context, TextView textView){
mContext = context;
mTextView = textView;
}
```

вместо

```
class MyClass(Context context, TextView textView){
    this.context = context; // глазам приятно видеть this 
    this.textView = textView;
  }
```

В коде громоздко получается:

```
private TextView mTextView;
mTextView = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_new_text_view);
```

Вместо:

```
private TextView textView;
textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_new_text_view);
```

Используете ли вы это соглашение в своих проектах?

Как относятся к использованию или игнорированию этого соглашения в крупных компаниях?

Как "Google" относится к игнорированию этого соглашения?

Comment: к сожалению, это оффтоп на SO. Вопросы-опросники запрещены...

Comment: @metalurgus как то его задать иначе ? или его удалят?

Comment: Ответ на этот  вопрос зависит от мнения. То есть правильного ответа на него нет. Такие вопросы тут задавать нельзя... Я лично на барабане вращал эти гайдлайны, они мне не нравятся, я их не использую.

Comment: Если вы будете использовать правила , принятые в соглашении, то другие разработчики, скажут вам спасибо за это. Отделение имен полей класса от локальных переменных малой буквой m ( или s для статических)  - большое удобство в плане читаемости кода, к нему быстро привыкаешь и потом долго проклинаешь всяких любителей доморощенной самодеятельности в написании имен. Следовать этому соглашению вас не могут насильно, но оно во-первых выстрадано болью в глазах тысяч тех, кто был до вас, а во-вторых говорит о вашем профессиональном уровне часто лучше резюме ( в котором можно и насочинять всякого)

Comment: а .. и да, гуглу вообще не интересно, как вы там свой код пишите - они его не читают. И это соглашения не android-девелопинга, а Java вообще. То есть, разрабатывая на каком-нибудь Golang (или С++) под андроид, вы должны придерживаться соглашений для того языка, на котором пишите, иначе вас уже Сишники не поймут с этими Явовскими конвенциями. Вообще же это **рекомендации** - писать вы можете, как вам удобно, но при соблюдении соглашений - это как писать грамотно. Вам вот нравится читать неграмотный текст?

Comment: @pavlofff, кстати на счет соглашения Java, а не андроид девелопмента, где это посмотреть можно? 
У Oracle в примерах не увидел ничего подобного
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137946.html#182

Comment: Это очень странно для меня, но вы правы. Соглашение Java действительно не включает наименование полей класса с малой m - это рекомендации гугл для андроид-разработчиков. Видимо я так давно занимаюсь исключительно андроид, что забыл, что когда то было не так. Прошу простить, что ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/168995/10105